# Choose different xib after connectionDidFinishLoading request

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xib

After `connectionDidFinishLoading` I would like to dynamically choose a different xib if the data is more then one item.  Is that possible?  The method is called after my request comes back.  However it keeps loading the original xib that has this class assigned to it through interface builder and crashes.  The original xib its using is called `TeamPoolViewController`.

```
- (NSMutableArray*) loadTableView {
    NSMutableArray *pools = [Pool getPools:[super parseResponse]];

    if([pools count] == 0)
        return pools;

    if([pools count] == 1)
    {
         self.view = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PoolsViewController" owner:self options:nil][0];
        return pools;
    }
    else
    {
        Pool *pool = [pools objectAtIndex:0];
        self.navigationItem.title = pool.name;
        return pool.poolTeams;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

```
PoolsViewController *poolsViewController = [PoolsViewController initWithNibName:@"PoolsViewController" bundle:nil];
NSView *poolsView = [poolsViewController view];
```

But, be advised: the poolsView will not be ready until it's unarchived from xib, it's not ready immediately when you load it from xib via initWithNibName:bundle:
You will be advised when it's ready in PoolsViewController awakeFromNib: